# Slow performance using ionic developing to Android

Tags: android, angularjs, performance, ionic-framework

When I run my app in an Iphone the application runs smoothly, it looks like native, but in Android is different, the transitions is lagged, slow, so I've tried to use crosswalk, it helps a little but still slow, what could it be? what can I do to increase the performance? I don't know if there is something to do with my code, so here it is:

```
<ion-list class="list list-inset">

            <ion-item class="item-button-right">

                {{"#" + pedidos.numero_pedido}}
                <p>{{"R$ "+pedidos.valor_total_formatado + " ( Condição: " + pedidos.condicao_de_pagamento + " )"}}</p>

                <p>{{pedidos.status_pedido }}</p>

                <div class="buttons">
                    {{pedidos._criado | amDateFormat:"DD/MM/YYYY"}} às {{pedidos._criado | amDateFormat:"HH:mm"}}
                </div>


            </ion-item>


        </ion-list>
```

controller:

```
.controller('PedidosDetalhesController', function ($scope, $stateParams, ShowList) {

        var pedidosId = $stateParams.pedidos_id;


        ShowList.pedidosPorId(pedidosId).then(function (listview) {
            $scope.pedidos = listview[0];

        });

        ShowList.faturamentoPedidos(pedidosId).then(function (listview) {
            $scope.faturamentos = listview;
        });

        ShowList.itensPedidos(pedidosId).then(function (listview) {
            $scope.itens = listview;
        });

        ShowList.clientePedido(pedidosId).then(function (listview) {
            $scope.clientesPedidos = listview[0];
        });


    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ng-repeat inside an ion-list, the huge count of the list item may be deteriorating the performance. You may instead want to use [collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)

> collection-repeat allows an app to show huge lists of items much more
>   performantly than ng-repeat.
>
> It renders into the DOM only as many items as are currently visible.
>
> This means that on a phone screen that can fit eight items, only the
>   eight items matching the current scroll position will be rendered.

**Usage :**

```
    <ion-content>
      <ion-item collection-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: when I use collection-repeat the items don't appear on the screen

Comment: `<ion-list>

            <ion-item class="item-button-right" collection-repeat="pedido in pedidos" href="#/app/pedidos/{{pedido.pedidos_id}}">

                {{"#" + pedido.numero_pedido}}
                <p>{{pedido.status_pedido}}</p>

                <div class="buttons">
                    {{pedido._criado | amDateFormat:"DD/MM/YYYY"}} às {{pedido._criado | amDateFormat:"HH:mm"}}
                </div>

            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>`

Comment: Please go through the attached link.. You must provide height and width for the item